# unable to create trigger from openwhisk kafka feed that listens to a Generic Kafka instance

Tags: openwhisk, serverless

I have openwhisk local installation on Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. Actions, triggers, rules and alarm triggers are working.

I cloned the git repository https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-package-kafka and ran the following in sequence:
installCatalog.sh , gradlew :distDocker, installKafka.sh

Then I tried to create a trigger:

```
bin/wsk trigger create MyKafkaTrigger -f /messaging/kafkaFeed -p brokers "
[\"localhost:9092\", \"localhost:9093\"]" -p topic test -p isJSONData true -
-insecure
```

I am following this section of the README: "Creating a Trigger that listens to a Generic Kafka instance"

I am re-using the Kafka instance created as part of Openwhisk installation, and created a topic named 'test' - I am able to publish / consume to this topic using kafka command line tools.

The trigger creation fails (it deletes the trigger, saying resource does not exist).

One thing I observed is that the following packages were created under /guest:

```
bin/wsk package list /guest --insecurepackages
/guest/messagingWeb                                                    
                     private
/guest/messaging
```

I did change the feed name to /guest/messaging/kafkFeed, only kafkaFeed, etc., but the results are slightly different:

```
bin/wsk trigger create MyKafkaTrigger -f /guest/messaging/kafkaFeed -p 
brokers "[\"localhost:9092\", \"localhost:9093\"]" -p topic test -p 
isJSONData true --insecure
```

GIVES a JSON output saying "error": "The requested resource does not exist."

```
bin/wsk trigger create MyKafkaTrigger -f /messaging/kafkaFeed -p brokers "
[\"localhost:9092\", \"localhost:9093\"]" -p topic test -p isJSONData true -
-insecure
```

GIVES

```
ok: deleted trigger MyKafkaTrigger
error: Unable to create trigger 'MyKafkaTrigger': Unable to invoke trigger 
'MyKafkaTrigger' feed action '/messaging/kafkaFeed'; feed is not configured: 
Unable to invoke action 'kafkaFeed': The supplied authentication is not 
authorized to access this resource. (code 186)
```

Looking for any help

Comment: Note that I am just planning to use a Generic Kafka instance without SASL . username / password / kafka admin (REST) url.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the dev guide to get up and running: https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-package-kafka/blob/master/devGuide.md

Here are the steps I did to get a feed trigger successfully created:

1. Take note of the auth key by running

   ```
   bin/wsk -i property get --auth
   ```
2. Run the install script

   ```
   ./installKafka.sh <authKey> <edgehost> <dburl> <dbprefix> <apihost>
   ```

Note that the value of `authKey` is the value obtained from step 1. For the values of the other parameters, see https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-package-kafka/blob/master/devGuide.md#install-actions

3. Once the install script completes successfully, verify that the correct packages are installed. You should see the `messaging` and `messagingWeb` packages. e.g

   ```
   bin/wsk -i package list /guest

   packages
   /guest/messagingWeb                                                    private
   /guest/messaging                                                       shared
   ```
4. Now verify that the `kafkaFeed` action exists

   ```
   bin/wsk -i package get --summary /guest/messaging

   package /guest/messaging: Returns a result based on parameter endpoint
      (parameters: *endpoint)
    action /guest/messaging/kafkaProduce: Produce a message to a Kafka cluster
      (parameters: base64DecodeKey, base64DecodeValue, brokers, key, topic, value)
    feed   /guest/messaging/kafkaFeed: Feed to listen to Kafka messages
      (parameters: brokers, endpoint, isBinaryKey, isBinaryValue, isJSONData, topic)
   ```
5. Now you can create a trigger by either passing in the namespace as part of the full package name, or leaving off the leading `/` from the package name

   ```
   bin/wsk -i trigger create MyKafkaTrigger -f /guest/messaging/kafkaFeed -p brokers "[\"localhost:9092\", \"localhost:9093\"]" -p topic test -p isJSONData true

   OR

   bin/wsk -i trigger create MyKafkaTrigger -f messaging/kafkaFeed -p brokers "[\"localhost:9092\", \"localhost:9093\"]" -p topic test -p isJSONData true
   ```

Comment: I had not seen the devGuide before. Nevertheless, #3 and #4 above work as expected. So I have probably set up the Feed correctly.                                   I missed the docker build and run steps. So now I followed those two steps as well. I am still getting same error on creating the trigger. One caveat though is that I cannot expose port 80:5000 in the docker since I am on a local setup where port 80 is already used by nginx coming from the openwhisk installation.  Could this be a reason for the failure?

Comment: The creation of a trigger is not dependent on the feed provider itself. You should be able to create a trigger even when it is not running

Comment: what is the result of running `bin/wsk -i property get --namespace`?

Comment: bin/wsk -i property get --namespace
whisk namespace                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                       
But the error message (JSON) shows namespace 'guest'                            
"namespace": "guest", ... "error": { "error": "The requested resource does not exist."}

Comment: try `bin/wsk -i property unset --namespace` and then try `trigger create` once again. if that doesn't help, perhaps you can open an issue in the repository and we can continue there?

Comment: tried unsetting the namespace and ran the command to create the trigger. But same problem remains. I will open an issue in the repository.  Want to add that I had the exact same problem with the alarm feed, but after using the (unofficial) ansible script written by Jason Peterson (https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-package-alarms/issues/51#issuecomment-294010619), it is working for me. But there is no similar ansible script for kafkaFeed that I know of.

Comment: Created a new issue: https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-package-kafka/issues/221